# GSON with DataTables spring mvc for empty data

Tags: jquery, json, spring, datatables, gson

I am using the `sAjaxSource` for fetching data from my spring controller which gives a json response.
Something like this

```
   [
   {
      "id":20009,
      "title":"1914 tran by H. Rackham",
      "description":"\"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charmces ",
      "username":"nessudi",
      "datecreated":"Apr 22, 2014 10:39:24 AM"
   },
   {
      "id":20008,
      "title":"The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s",
      "description":"\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\"",
      "username":"naai",
      "datecreated":"Apr 22, 2014 10:38:46 AM"
   },
   {
      "id":20065,
      "title":"Where to get Lorem Ipsum",
      "description":"Therpetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.",
      "username":"nensi",
      "datecreated":"Apr 22, 2014 10:37:34 AM"
   },
   {
      "id":20056,
      "title":"What is Lorem Ipsum",
      "description":"Lorrinter took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ",
      "username":"xyz",
      "datecreated":"Apr 22, 2014 10:28:39 AM"
   }
]
```

Although when there is no data the datatable show "Loading......" message.

I read through other posts which suggested to send empty array with "{aaData:[ ]}"..but I am using 
"sAjaxDataProp": "" ..so my data property is null.. How do i handle this? I am using the gson library in java.

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/theurl", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String somemethod(){
        List<someobject> listobjs = this.someService.getobjsList();
        if(listobjs != null){
            Collections.sort(listobjs, Collections.reverseOrder());
        }
        return gson.toJson(listobjs);
    }
```

Here is my Datatable creation

```
$("#myTable").dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/theurl",
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sEmptyTable":     "My Custom Message On Empty Table"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "bSort" : false,
            "aoColumnDefs" : [
                               {"aTargets": [0],
                                "mRender" : function (data, type, full){
                                    return '<input style="float:left; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;" class="selected" type="checkbox" value="' + data + '">';
                                }   
                               }
                               ],
            "aoColumns" : [{"mData" : "id"},
                           {"mData" : "title"},
                           {"mData" : "description"},
                           {"mData" : "datecreated"}],

            "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json){
                //I do something here after init.
            }
             });
```

It works perfectly fine when there is some data in the list, but when the list is empty the Datatable just shows "Loading" message and i get type error: cannot handle null exception in browser console errors.
I have temporarily fixed it by writing some jquery code to replace the "Loading..." message. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be related to how you represent an empty list.

Your controller seems to output "null", when listobjs is null.
The datatables plugin assumes an empty Javascript array, "[]" .. hence the type error.

Your should change your controller to just return an empty List, if the listobjs is null, such as

```
final ArrayList<SomeObject> empty = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
gson.toJson(empty);
```

This could also be handled in your service controller, so you don't need to change anything.

As a side note: If you are already using Spring and are not relying on Gson specifics, you could simplify your code a lot by using the built in jackson marshaller - which lets you return the List object directly.

```
@RequestMapping("/theurl")
public
@ResponseBody
List<SomeObject> somemethod() {
    // call to service
    return listobjs;
}
```

The second example just works, if you add the necessary jackson jars to the classpath - if you are using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```